# How to use Markov Chain to calculate attribution worth of a state?

Tags: markov-process

I am trying to model a user's behavior through an app and have come across the idea of Markov Chains to do the modeling. A similar problem in marketing seems to be the multi-channel attribution problem. What I don't quite understand is how to attribute the positive outcome's result to each node along the way since my paths can be bidrectional.

[image]

In the image above, how do I attribute the purchase conversion to the Notification Center with markov chains? I've tried to see if there was a removal effect, but since the node itself doesn't touch the conversion path directly, it doesn't seem to change. Is the attribution of it just 0 then?

Comment: Just a question to clarify what you mean by "attribution": The attribution of the Store in this would be 10% and the the attribution of Social would be 5%, is that correct?

Comment: Right, landing in Store results in a 10% purchase conversion. So all traffic driven into Store, no matter the path, culminates in a 10% purchase conversion worth x dollars. The question I have is now how do I go another step back and try to attribute Notification Center (NC).

If I use the traffic driven into the Store directly from NC and attribute it proportionally, I feel like I lose attributing any traffic that the NC might drive to Social and then finally back to the Store. How to deal with these and bidrectional loops is what confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the attribution of a node $N$ one can calculate the [Removal Effect](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2016/06/30/marketing-channel-attribution-markov-models-r/), i.e. the probability of a Purchase if the node $N$ "didn't exist" (= Exit note). This can be done by

1. setting the outgoing transition probabilities of $N$ to 0 except for the transition to Exit, which is set to 1: $P(\text{Exit}|N) = 1$.
2. calculate the resulting probability to purchase $P(\text{Purchase}|\text{Open App})$
3. and comparing with the case where the node operates normally.

Let's do this...

**Send Notification Center to Exit**

The node transition matrix $\underline{P}$ now looks as follows:

$$
\scriptsize{
\begin{matrix}
{} &  Open App &  Social &  Store &  Notification Center &  Exit &  Purchase \\
Open App            &       0.0 &    0.00 &    0.0 &                  0.0 &   0.0 &       0.0 \\
Social              &       0.5 &    0.00 &    0.4 &                  0.0 &   0.0 &       0.0 \\
Store               &       0.5 &    0.30 &    0.0 &                  0.0 &   0.0 &       0.0 \\
Notification Center &       0.0 &    0.15 &    0.1 &                  0.0 &   0.0 &       0.0 \\
Exit                &       0.0 &    0.50 &    0.4 &                  1.0 &   1.0 &       0.0 \\
Purchase            &       0.0 &    0.05 &    0.1 &                  0.0 &   0.0 &       1.0 \\
\end{matrix}
}
$$

**Calculate resulting probability of a purchase**

Define $\vec \pi$ as the initial state vector (100%, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) in the order of the above columns, i.e. at the start all the money is in the Open App node. Then we calculate the probabilities after a long time has passed (e.g. 1000 times steps). This yields $$\vec\pi \underline P^{1000} = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 88.6\%, 11.4\%)
$$

**Compare with default case**
This without sending everything from Notification Center directly to Exit, the chain yields $$\vec\pi \underline P_{default}^{1000} = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 86.3\%, 13.7\%)
$$

> Accordingly, we can now argue that out of 100\$ that could potentially
>   be spent in purchases, 2.3\$ would "get lost" if the Notification Center didn't exist (13.7\$ minus 11.4\$).

Comment: Thanks @Denwid. I've been reading around this literature too. It seems the Removal Effect makes a pretty strong assumption that traffic going one way would strictly be redirected to the exit. In reality though, through a user journey through the app, if they were going to a certain node that doesn't exist, I would expect them to just go somewhere different in the app as opposed to going strictly to the exit. Seems like a really big assumption being made, but I guess this is still better than nothing.

Comment: I you believe a weaker assumption would be better, you could just replace the Notification Center column in P accordingly, e.g. set Exit to only 50pct and distribute the other 50pct evenly among the other nodes: pi = (0, 0.5/3, 0.5/3, 0, 0.5, 0.5/3).

Answer (score 0):

Since the attribution to the Store is the probability `P(Purchase|Store)`, the corresponding attribution for the Notification Center is `P(Purchase|Notification Center)` and with the [chain rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29?wprov=sfla1) this can be decomposed as `P(Purchase|Store)*P(Store|Notification Center) + P(Purchase|Social)*P(Social|Notification Center)`.

Plugging in the numbers thus yields `0.1*0.35+0.05*0.55` which is 0.0625 or 6.25%.

The nice things about Markov chains is *exactly* that you don't have to worry about loops, since the probabilities are always depending only on the previous state.

Comment: So the chain rule you used is adding these paths:
`NC --> Store --> Purchase`,
`NC --> Social --> Purchase`.


Somehow these paths are baked into that probability too?


`NC --> Store --> Social --> Purchase`, 
`NC --> Social --> Store --> Purchase`

Comment: Yes. That's the Markov property. Once you're at Store your probability to end up at Purchase is always the same (0.1).

Comment: Makrov Property intuitively says it doesn't matter where you came from or looped a 1000 times before.

Comment: Okay, to clarify, if we put dollar values to it. 10% Store purchase conversions, 5% Social conversions totalling $100. `Store = 0.1 / (0.1 + 0.05) * $100 = $66.67`. `Social = 0.05 / (0.1 + 0.05) * $100 = $33.33`. `NC = .0625 / (0.1 + 0.05) * $100 = $41.67`?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't propagate it back this way. Dividing 6.25% by 0.15 doesn't yield anything useful. The 6.25% simply tell you the probability of a purchase once the user is in the Notification Center. Sorry I didn't get that you wanted to propagate 100$ back through the chain.

Comment: By the way it's also wrong to say `Store = 0.1 / (0.1 + 0.05) * $100 = $66.67. Social = 0.05 / (0.1 + 0.05) * $100 = $33.33`, since P(Purchase|Social) doesn't say anything about how many "dollars" (i.e. users purchasing in the end) even ended up at Social in the first place.